# Solution of Klein-Kramers Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I would like to ask to those, who have experience with PDE in stochastic process, for a bit of help. Here, I bring the Klein-Kramers equation which is a linear second-order PDE, given by

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{P}{M}\left[\frac{\partial  \rho}{\partial X}\right]+ M\omega^2 X \left[\frac{\partial  \rho}{\partial P}\right]  +\gamma\left[\frac{\partial  \left(P\rho\right)}{\partial P}\right]  +D\left[\frac{\partial^2  \rho}{\partial P^2}\right],
\end{align}

where $\rho=\rho(X,P)$, $M$ is the particle mass, $\gamma$ is the dissipation factor, and $\omega$ is the harmonic oscillator frequency. Basically, the equation describes a Brownian particle in the phase space, i.e, in the space of position $X$ and momentum $P$. To get directly to the point, I want the solution of it, but so far I have not found it. In my attempt, I considered at first the Fourier transform, since it reduces the previous second-order differential equation to a first-order one. This is

\begin{align}
\dot{R} = \frac{k_1}{m}\left[\frac{\partial  R}{\partial k_2}\right] -M\omega^2 k_2 \left[\frac{\partial  R}{\partial k_1}\right] - \gamma k_2\left[\frac{\partial  R}{\partial k_2}\right] + Dk_2^2\,R,
\end{align}

where $R=R(k_1,k_2,t) \equiv FT\left[\rho(X,P,t)\right]$. Then, I considered the method of characteristics using as initial condition that $\rho(X,P,0)=\delta(X)\delta(P)$, i.e., $R(k_1,k_2,0)=1$. However, I did not manage to find the solution. Actually, it would be already nice, if anyone knows how to get the solution of the differential equation above without the harmonic term, I mean:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{P}{M}\left[\frac{\partial  \rho}{\partial X}\right]  +\gamma\left[\frac{\partial  \left(P\rho\right)}{\partial P}\right]  +D\left[\frac{\partial^2  \rho}{\partial P^2}\right].
\end{align}

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question

Comment: Look again there

Comment: OP did you ever find an answer to your question of solution to classical Kramers equation?

Comment: Typically this equation is solved in the literature by noting that the joint process (X,V) is a linear transformation of a Gaussian random variable. Therefore it is also Gaussian. One then finds the drift and diffusion vectors of the joint process from the defining Langevin equations. These vectors are sufficient to characterize the 2D Gaussian solution of the Kramers equation with a linear potential. It is seriously hard to solve the equation any other way. Because of this limited capability we have, Kramers' equations with non-linear potentials pose a serious challenge.

Comment: See the recent book by Kwok on Langevin equations, pg 27 for the solution @Arthur - i saw this today.